# Event handling in Wijmo SpreadJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Wijmo SpreadJS and I'm trying to implement event handling. So, basically I want to control cell clicking.

This is how my code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // code here //

  initSpread();

});

function initSpread(){
  // code here //
};

$("#ss").wijspread();
var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");
var activeSheet = spread.getActiveSheet();

activeSheet.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.CellClick, function (sender, args) {
    alert("Cell "+args.col+args.row+" clicked");
});
```

This is returning the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getActiveSheet'
```

What is wrong with this code? 
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

When you create instance of spreadjs, you should give a sheet count, otherwise there is no sheet in spreadjs.
$("#ss").wijspread({sheetCount:1});